# Include different PhoneGap assets in different Xcode targets?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am trying to include different assets in different Xcode targets for a suite of PhoneGap apps. The apps all use essentially the same code, but each requires a large amount of different image and sound files.

I understand how to create a new target in Xcode (4.3.2), and how to include/exclude specific files or bundles by using the "Target Membership" pane on the right-hand side of Project view.

However, this option is not available for assets within the blue PhoneGap **www** folder.

I could give each target its own **www** folder, but then I'm not sure how to reuse html and javascript across the different targets.

Comment: Hi, i am also looking for this. If you found any solution. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, and not portable. But ... For each target with separate assets, create a sibling folder next to **www**. (Use the Target Membership pane to assign it to appropriate target.) To access these assets from the PhoneGap app, you need to know the full path to this folder. You can find that by examining window.location.href.